# Analog sound trouble Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I try to play mp3 files with mpg321, mpg123 and omxplayer with hdmi works fine, but with the analog audio jack doesn't work
I have installed alsa-tools and alsamixergui

I set the audio jack output:

```
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
```

I test the speakers with

```
speaker-test -t sine -f 600
```

and works well, I can hear the sound, but when I try to play an mp3 file with :

```
omxplayer bubbling_water_1.mp3
mpg321 bubbling_water_1.mp3
```

not hear any sound at all, the same mp3 file play ok with hdmi output

```
sudo amixer cset numid=3 0
```

or

```
sudo amixer cset numid=3 2
```

but nothing happens on analog jack output
any help ?

Answer (score 6):

I noticed this same problem. I haven't found a permanent solution yet, but what works for me is the following:

```
omxplayer -o local file.mp3
```

The audio comes out over HDMI, by the way, and the -o local flag forces it to line-out (local).

Comment: I was trying with the above commands and mpg123, after executing
'code' sudo amixer cset numId = 3 1
the speaker made ​​a noise, from then on everything works fine, mpg123, mpg321, oxmplayer

Comment: +1 Seems like this is the only solution that worked for me so far with omxplayer.

Comment: I still have no control over the volume, but at least this got it to output to analog. +1

Comment: I've tried this (`omxplayer`) and the sound does work, but the volume is *very* low in the external speaker I've attached. I tested the speaker on another device and the audio output is fine, I don't know why omxplayer is so low on the Rpi.

Answer (score 1):

I had pulseaudio installed in my Raspberry Pi, so I had to use the variant [described here](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Sound_does_not_work_at_all.2C_or_in_some_applications):

`amixer -c 0 cset numid=3 1`

The `-c 0` indicates which card to use. This worked for me.

I also set the volume to maximum using `alsamixer` just in case, but I'm not sure it was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just start omx with the `--vol` switch.
Type `omxplayer --vol -1000 filename`
and you will notice the difference.
Volume ranges from 0 to -6000.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
```

to re-direct the output to the 3.5 mm jack

```
last digit 
  0 = auto
  1 = 3.5 mm
  2 = HDMI
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also important to notice that **omxplayer doesn't use default alsa setting** (which is set by raspi-config).
By default it is in auto mode, which means if HDMI is connected and EDID reports audio support, then it uses HDMI, otherwise analogue (headphone jack). (See [issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/68)).

```
omxplayer -o local
```

or

```
omxplayer -o hdmi
```

can be used to override this.
That's why omxplayer can give different results than other players like mpg123.

Comment: This would explain why I am unable to adjust the volume from the system tray. +1